# Using CSS directly into Mou without changing the CSS Stylesheet attached to it

Tags: html, css

I am currently using Mou for some note taking and to list the functions of a website.
I know that Mou allows the user to use HTML in his document but I didn't find anything about including CSS directly into Mou via HTML.

So here is what I wrote for now.

```
* function listed 
<span style: "color: red;">**(something important I have to say to my co-worker)** </span>
```

I have also tried to add this at the start of my Mou file.

```
<style type="text/css">
span { color: red; }
</style>
```

But no luck either way.

Mou doesn't register the style I added in the span nor at the start of the Mou file.
I know I could be using more emphasizing like so.

```
***This could be a solution***
```

But I want this text to be red (because it's really important and red text is cool).

Is there anyway to include CSS directly into Mou or do I have to go into Mou's CSS stylesheet to make some changes ?

Answer (score 1):

`<span style: "color: red;">` is wrong, use `<span style="color: red;">`. If that doesnt work, overwrite it harder: `<span style="color: red !important;">`